# Cite Custom Field in apacite

Tags: bibtex, citing, apacite

I am trying to find a command that will allow me to cite any field in my document. For instance, I would like to reference `ibcnn`, specify the field `title` and print `Local Binary Convolutional Neural Networks`, or specify field `month` and print `2017`.

```
@journal{ibcnn,
 title={{Local Binary Convolutional Neural Networks}},
 author={Felix Juefei-Xu and Vishnu Naresh Boddeti and Marios Savvides},
 booktitle={{IEEE} Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition ({CVPR})},
 month={July},
 year={2017}
}
```

I'm sure this can be achieved but for some reason I am not able to — even looking at the `bibtex` package I cannot find how to do that simply.

Comment: This would be possible to do using `biblatex` (but quite a bit of work depending on how general it needs to be) ) but very hard with traditional `bibtex` methods. But I don't think there's any package which gives you this functionality out of the box.

Comment: Are you actually using the `apacite` package?

Comment: @AlanMunn Not sure; this is how I get `apacite`: `\documentclass[jou, apacite]{apa6}`

Comment: @AlanMunn with regards to `biblatex`, trying to import using `\usepackage{biblatex}` doesn't work, seems to conflict with `apacite`. I'm open to creative solutions though

Comment: @AlanMunn do you have any ideas?

Comment: As I suggested in my previous comment, this is a non-trivial task for which no package currently exists. Why do you need this functionality?  Because effectively you're asking someone to write a package for you, which unless it has some general rationale people are unlikely to do. (I understand that wasn't  your intention, of course.)